# Como fazer um for sequencial com nodejs versão 8?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loop, assincronismo

A versão do nodejs é: v8.10.0

Não tenho muito conhecimento com node. Nesse caso específico preciso que a próxima iteração seja executada somente depois da iteração anterior ser finalizada. Além disso, preciso que quando aconteça alguma exceção, o for seja parado e que mais nenhuma iteração aconteça.

Achei que usando `break` resolveria meu problema para interromper o for mas não funcionou.

Obs: Realmente preciso fazer isto na versão 8, na versão 11 eu fazia sem problemas. Mas nesta versão estou tendo dificuldades.

```
for (let i = 0; i < modelMatchesList.length; i++) {
    if (someVar) {
         DB.query("example(?,?)", [foo, bar])
         .then((result) => {
             doSomething(result);
         })
         .then(() => {
             doSomething();
         })
         .catch((e) => {
             // Caso tenha alguma excpetion
             // Parar e sair do for
         })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O operador `await`, que foi adicionado no `ES6`, serve para simplificar o encadeamento de promessas, que é o que você especificou.

> [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)
>
> O operador `await` é utilizado para esperar por uma `Promise`. Ele pode ser usado apenas dentro de uma `async function`.

Seu código convertido seria algo parecido com o seguinte:

```
const execute = async (list, someVar, foo, bar) => {
  for (const item in list ) {
    if (!someVar) {
      continue;
    }

    const result = await DB.query("example(?,?)", [foo, bar]);
    await doSomething(result);
    await doSomething();
  }
};
```

E você faria a chamada dessa função da seguinte forma:

```
const execution = async () => {
  try {
    await execute(['a', 'b'], true, 1, 'x');
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e.message);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tente adicionar um `await` antes da sua query.

```
await DB.query("example(?,?)", [foo, bar])
```

E no caso de parar a iteração caso necessite, tente adicionar um `return false`

Exemplo:

```
for ( let n = 0; n <= 10; n++ ) {
  if ( someVar ) {
    // Some code
  }
  else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Percebi que você está usando um `.then()` após outro... Não sei se entendi a sua pergunta, mas caso queira que o segundo `.then()` só execute após a finalização do primeiro, você deve, dentro do primeiro, refazer a query do banco. Exemplo (você também poderá usar o `throw` para finalizar imediatamente a execução de um script:

```
DB.query("example(?,?)", [foo, bar])
   .then((result) => {
      if (!result) throw false
      DB.query("example(?,?)", [foo, bar])
       .then((result) => {
           if (!result) throw false
           doSomething()
       })
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia tentar usar o await antes de DB.query ja que ele é uma promise, porém ele vai funcionar somente se esse for estiver dentro de uma função async. É bom dar uma olhada se o a versão 8 do node tem suporte ao async e await, quase certeza que tem!
(Eu colocaria essa resposta mais como um comentario do que uma resposta definitiva porém o StackOverflow diz que não tenho reputação suficiente para comentar, então vai como resposta mesmo)

Answer (score -1):

let cont = 0;

const limit = modelMatchesList.length;

for (let i = 0; i < modelMatchesList.length; i++) {

```
if (someVar) {

    DB.query("example(?,?)", [foo, bar]);

}
count++

if (count == limit) {

    doSomething(result);


}
```

}